# Python Programming Error: Column Does Not Exist

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I looked into some of the other causes for this and was unable to find an answer. The table is not created in "" and the cases are exactly the same. My create table statement is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    name VARCHAR(30), 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    wins INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    matches INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);
```

And I am running the following PostgreSQL query (in a Python function - inserts a player into the database):

```
query = "INSERT INTO players (name) VALUES (%s);"
```

Followed by this one:

```
query = "SELECT id, name, wins, matches\
FROM players ORDER BY wins DESC;"
```

When I attempt to run the script, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "id" of relation "players" does not exist
```

I have tried taking out the id column and just selecting wins as well, but it tells me it does not exist either. I've also tried changing up the players table to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    name VARCHAR(30), 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    wins INTEGER, 
    matches INTEGER
);
```

And the INSERT statement being:

```
query = "INSERT INTO players (name, wins, matches) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);"
c.execute(query,(name,0,0))
```

And receive the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "wins" of relation "players" does not exist
```

I've run a simple SELECT * FROM players; in my terminal, and it returns this table, so the columns are definitely there...

```
 name | id | wins | matches 
------+----+------+---------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Does the connection string point to the same port and database as you connect from the terminal? Post both the connection string and the command to the terminal client.

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ `name` [is not a reserved key word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html#KEYWORDS-TABLE)

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ the name column was working just fine before I made some formatting changes and combined some tables, now I can't get anything to work.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I'm sorry, I'm very new to this so I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: What is the result of "SHOW search_path" in your application and in psql?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Thanks for the heads up

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you found the problem, @RebeccaTauber? I'm struggling with that very same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that before their wasn't any foreign key in the table which you've deleted cause that may be the problem db isn't reading any columns as it will be unable to find any reference to the key.
Try re-designing the schema.

Comment: Here are the prior tables:

Comment: CREATE TABLE scores (playerid SERIAL, wins INTEGER, matches INTEGER);

Comment: CREATE TABLE players (name TEXT, playerid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

Comment: Their is nothing wrong in tables and psycopg2 connectivity, here is the sample code in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> con = psycopg2.connect(database='game',user='postgres',password='root',
           host='localhost',port=5432)
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> var = 'name_input'
>>> cur.execute("""INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('%s')""" %(var))
>>> win = 1
>>> match = 3
>>> cur.execute("""INSERT INTO scores(wins,matches) VALUES (%d,%d)""" %(win,match))
>>> con.commit()
>>> cur.execute("""INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('%s')""" %(var))
>>> con.commit()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM players")
>>> data = cur.fetchall()
>>> data
[('name_input', 3), ('name_input', 4)]
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM scores")
>>> data = cur.fetchall()
>>> data
[(1, 1, 3)]
```